# Reescribir URL con .htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estoy con un proyecto usando el modelo-vista-controlador y quiero hacer que la url sea "amigable". Para ello quiero cambiar parte de la url para que me rescriba la parte de la url que pone **/?zona=menu-javascript** y me deje solo **/menu-javascript.**

Entiendo que esto lo tengo que hacer mediante un archivo  .htacces. Este archivo le tengo y tiene este codigo:

```
#Activar RewriteEngine
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 #Reescribir la URL solicitada por el usuario
 #Entrada: seccion partiendo desde raiz
 #Salida: ?zona=seccion

 RewriteRule ^([a-zAZ0-9]+)$ ?zona=$1 

 ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Hago la peticion a cada zona de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
 session_start();

 $componente = (isset($_GET['zona'])) ? $_GET['zona'] : 'home';

 function loader($componente) {

  ob_start();
  include 'componentes/' . $componente . '/controller.php';
  $buffer = ob_get_clean();
  return $buffer;
  }
```

Creo que el patron es correcto pero no me funciona. ¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias.

Comment: al no incluir el guion en el patrón no te tomará "menu-javascript"

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Al final lo conseguí, tenia un fallo tonto. Tu respuesta es correcta. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al no incluir el guion en el patrón no te tomará "menu-javascript", podes incluir todo y luego filtrar en el `$_GET`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ?zona=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

---

```
<?php
 session_start();

 $componentesValidos = array('menu-javascript', 'menu-otro', 'home');

 $componente = 
    ( isset($_GET['zona']) && 
      in_array($_GET['ZONA'], $componentesValidos) ) ? 
      $_GET['zona'] : 'home';

 function loader($componente) {
   $buffer = '';
   $componenteFile = 'componentes/' . $componente . '/controller.php';
   if(file_exists($componenteFile)) :
     ob_start();
     include ($componenteFile);
     $buffer = ob_get_clean();
   endif;
   return $buffer;
 }
```

**editado**  añadido `RewriteBase` para sortear ciertas situaciones donde se pierde el "`basedir`" del `RewriteRule`. en este caso es `/` si movés el proyecto dentro de una subcarpeta sera la ruta relativa al dominio.